# Заменить значение в определенном месте

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть к примеру див:

```
<div name="klass[1][2]"></div>
```

Как мне проверить значение внутри вторых квадратных скобок (в данном случае "2") и заменить на нужное мне значение?

Comment: Решил вопрос уже, но всем спасибо. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

метод replace позволяет применить свою функцию для вычисления замены

```
function change2ndInd(str, i1, i2, offset) {
  if(i2==2) return "["+i1+"]["+i2*3+"]";
  else return str;
}

var result = "klass[1][2]".replace(/\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/gi, change2ndInd);
alert(result); // klass[1][6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Много способов, например так

```js
$(function() {

  value = 'замена';

  var data = $('div').attr('name').replace(/(.+)(\[.+?\])\[(.+?)\]/gi, '$1$2[' + value + ']');
  $('div').attr('name', data);


  $('div').after(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="klass[1][2]"></div>
```